# Hibernate HQL: How to select Parent entity if and only if ALL Child entities have a property with same value?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Guess I have two entities with bidirectional `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` associations:

`Parent` -- has many --> `Child`
`Child` has a `boolean` property `x`.

I want to select `Parent` entities where all associated `Child` entities have `x` set to `true`.
For example if I have data as below:

Parent:

```
+-------+       
|   ID  | 
+-------+       
|   1   |  
+-------+       
|   2   |  
+-------+
```

Child:

```
+-------+-------+-------+       
|   ID  | P.ID  |   x   |
+-------+-------+-------+       
|   1   |   1   | true  |
+-------+-------+-------+       
|   2   |   1   | true  |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   3   |   2   | true  |
+-------+-------+-------+       
|   4   |   2   | false | 
+-------+-------+-------+
```

I want a HQL or JPQL query that returns `Parent` entity with `id` 1.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may execute this query:

```
from parent p where p.ID in (select c.parent from child c where c.x=true) and p.ID not in (select c.parent from child c where c.x = false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jpql` query like this

```
select p from Parent p where p.children is not empty and not exists(
    select 1 from p.children c where c.x=false)
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
   //...

   @OneToMany
   List<Child> children;

   //...
}
```

Comment: What is 1 in "select 1 from p.children" ?

Comment: You can use `select c from` instead of  `select 1 from`. The result would be the same. `select 1 from` is used to simplify selection object. If `c.x=false` subquery returns 1 so `not exists(1) = false`. Otherwise `not exists(nothing) = true`.